# C# detect which C# (.cs / poco) files have changed during second run of the application at run time

Tags: c#, .net, hash, cqrs, event-sourcing

I would like to detect which C# files (pocos) have changed the second time I run the application compared to the previous run. By a change, I mean any change to the file eg change to the logic inside a method or addition/removal of properties/fields. You can assume the file name stays the same. Inspecting git logs/changes is out of scope for this problem.

Potential solutions I can think of is to keep a record of the hash in the database. I can calculate the hash of the file or calculate the hash of the instance of the poco object. Calculating the hash of the file will give me a unique hash, but during runtime, all the .cs files get compiled into dll so it may not be possible to do this within a single project, I would need to have a separate project run before the main project to populate the hashes (not ideal). Or I can I hash the object instance, but I don’t think that considers the code changes in the method/functions of the poco as it’s only hashing the property/field values (correct me here if I’m wrong).

I am wondering if there a straight forward way of doing this? Potentially a solution where I can get a unique hash of the file at runtime, save it to database for second run. On the second run, compare the new hashes I just generated to the values in the database and operate on any changes that were made.

So at this point, I'm not sure what possible methods are there to tackle this issue. Any pointers or advice on how to tackle this would be helpful.

---

Background context to the problem:

In a CQRS system, we have projections, and any changes to the views/projections require the events to be replaying onto the projection to rebuild the view. This can be expensive if the event database is large. So I've built some tools to allow all the all views/projections to be rebuilt for application startup in development and for production, ability to optionally recreate some views for speed that have changed during the sprint. To optionally recreate views, we have to find out which views changed during the sprint and pass it in as an environment variable so the only the correct views should be rebuilt to speed up the startup time of the application. This is a manual process and human error can occur easily where we may miss a view that may have changed. I'd like automatically detect the views that have changed during the sprint at the application startup, by checking the files that have changed and use this change list to rebuild the views.

Thanks in advance for all the help :)

Comment: Do you use source control?

Comment: @ParrishHusband yes we do

Comment: Are .tt files ignored?

Comment: I'm not familiar with .tt files, can you explain how they can be used to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you using a CI/CD Pipeline or a BuildServer ? (I guess so, but please state which exactly)

Comment: Azures devops CI/CD build/release pipeline.

Comment: I was thinking of a build-step that would compile some sort of config file from the git - info, so you could start replays on startup based on that config file ... just a crude idea. Don't know if that's actually feasible.

Comment: @Fildor yes that would work, but I'm really hoping that there is a solution where I can do this at runtime from the base project.

Comment: Decompile your `dll` and check if the output changed. - eg. use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler

Comment: The updated solution below to use a T4 transform to generate the hashes at build time is probably the best answer. StackOverflow is not the place to find a ready-made solution; here is where you can learn more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process

Answer (score 1):

Use a source control system. Today Git is what most people use. Visual Studio has support for Git (see [Version Control in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/?view=vs-2019)). Personally I prefer to use the [Git Extensions for Visual Studio](https://gitextensions.github.io/).

These extensions have a browser that allows to compare commits. All code changes are highlighted. The old code is red, the new code is green.

---

**UPDATE**

You could create a hash code from the properties that are in a type, to see whether they have changed:

```
public static int GetPropertyHash(Type type) {
    int hash = 237463;
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties()) {
        unchecked {
            hash = hash * 17 + prop.Name.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 17 + prop.PropertyType.FullName.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
    return hash;
}
```

If this is not sufficient, then create a separate application that calculates the hash of the relevant code files and stores the result as C# code file into this project. Or use a T4 template inside the project to generate this file. The generated file could be something like this:

```
public static class SouceCode
{
    public static Dictionary<string, int> Hash => new Dictionary<string, int> {
        ["MyView1.cs"] = 1382683,
        ["MyPoco.cs"] = -598674579,
    };
}
```

Comment: I think my question may not have been clear, We do use GIT and can see the change list in the git logs but that's not what I want. I want to check which files have changed the second time I run the application compared to the previous run.

Answer (score 0):

The hash is only different if you use the built-in String.GetHashCode method (inherited from Object). If you use your own hashing method (more difficult), or an implementation such as HashCode (in .NET Core), you get what you want.

Comment: I tried hashing based on this post:
https://alexmg.com/posts/compute-any-hash-for-any-object-in-c

Would this kind of hashing take into account the logical changes inside the methods?

Comment: A proper hashing function should not produce different results if the string to be hashed didn't change.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have expressed my self properly. You can hash a file, or you can hash an object. Hashing a file during runtime is not possible, because that poco file will be compiled to dll?? Hashing an object is only hashing on the field/property values of the object correct? I.e Hashing an object instance does not take into account the code inside the method correct?

Comment: I understand now. Your question was a bit unclear. You can hash the file contents (as a string) or the instance. I was talking about the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a stable hash is part of the solution, already covered in other answers.

If you need access to the C# files at runtime, you'll need to copy them somehow at build time. In the project file, you can either Embed the files and then extract them from the assembly manifest, or Copy the files to bin/ and read them off disk.